# Tracking price from multiple e-commerce websites

Tags: mac, tracking

I remember seeing some softwares or web services that allow me to track prices of products.
I just can't remember what they were.

I need a tool that can track some prices of products from tigerdirect, amazon, newegg, etc.
I just want the tool to ping/email me when there is change in prices.

I'm also a mac user, so if there is some kind of notifier tool, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't come across an all-in-one tool for monitoring these websites, but [apnoti](http://www.apnoti.com/index/index) is great for Amazon. Apnoti (Amazon Price Notifier) also has [browser add-ons](http://www.apnoti.com/index/download) to make things even easier.

One way to check for deals on all sites though is to use RSS feeds. All of these sites have feeds available which you could use with a [feed reader](http://www.utsire.com/shrook/).